# Force Teamcity to Ignore tool version in a .net project

Tags: c#, msbuild, teamcity, teamcity-9.1

I am trying to build ASP.NET MVC project using Teamcity. In my .CSProj file, we have specified ToolVersion 4.0. Which means TeamCity will use MSBuild verison 4.0 to build the project. On our build server this is not available. **Can I force TeamCity to ignore this setting and use a new version of MSBuild.**

This is how my .csproj file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set `MSBuild version` in runner option.

**Like this :**

[image]

Comment: i tried it but it seems this option is overridden by ToolVersion in my .csproj file.

Comment: You need to check your agent properties for that.